# Building a Custom Search block

Tags: forms, database, blocks, search

I have to search the entered text in a drupal table and if there is a match for the keyword get all the fields corresponding to that keyword. I have executed the query and I have the fields to be printed in a array called $column_name.

How can I display these fields to the user in the form of a table?

```
function module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$text = $form_state['values']['text_field'];
$query = db_select('table_name', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('field_1','field_2','field_3'));
$query->condition('n.field_0', $text, '=');
$column_name = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Why are you not able to do this with a view and filtering with a search exposed filter?

Comment: I am able to do that way. I am a beginner, I want to try it this way.

Comment: So far you've started a bunch of facts, but not any question. You should edit your question to ask some thing specific, so readers know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I created two forms and called the second one only after the first form is submitted. To create a table i used table theme.

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['text'])) {


 //db_query here to search the key word
 $text = $form_state['values']['text'];
$header=array(t('patient id'), t('patient name'));
$row = array( 
    array(
t('one'),t('two')
    ),
);

 $form['table']=array(
 '#theme'=>'table',
 '#header'=>$header,
 '#rows'=>$row,
 ); 
 }
 else {

 $form['text'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('patient_id'
));

 $form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit Button'),
//'#ajax'=> array('callback'=>'anonymous_page'),

); 
}
return $form;
}
```

in the form submit add

```
$form_state['rebuild']=true;
```